# Are the values of these two continuous functions equal?

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f$ defined on the nonnegative reals such that 
$f(x)=x$ for all nonnegative $x$ and the *continuous* function $g$ defined on the nonnegative reals such that $g(0)=0$, $g^{\prime}(3)=987654321$, and $g^{\prime}(x) = 1$ for all nonnegative $x \neq 3$.

Does $f(x)=g(x)$ for all nonnegative $x$? Why or why not?

This does not make sense to me because $\int_\limits{0}^cf^{\prime}(u)\text{ d}u=\int_\limits{0}^cg^{\prime}(u)\text{ d}u$ for all $c$, which
should imply $f(x)=g(x)$ for all nonnegative $x$, but that would imply that the derivatives are always equal.

Comment: [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) tells us that the derivative of any differentiable function satisfies the intermediate value theorem, which your $g'(x)$ does not.  Hence it can not be the derivative of a function.

Comment: @yuri12345 You have asked the same question three times in a row now. You will keep getting the same sort of answers this way. If you don't understand an answer, or are looking for a different explanation, then either use the comments or edit the question specifying what you still need. Do not post a new identical question.

Answer (score 1):

We have a continuous function $g :[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ such that $g(0) = 0$, $g'(3) = 987654321$ and $g'(x) = 1$ for $x \ne 3$. This means that $g$ is differentiable. Hence we have $g(x) = x$ on $[0,3)$ and $g(x) = x +c$ on $(3,\infty)$. By continuity we see that $g(3) = 3$ and $c = 0$. Thus $g'(3) = 1 \ne 987654321$. Therefore there *does not exist* any $g$ as in your question.

Thus the natural answer seems to be "no". However, you may also argue that the answer is "yes" for purely formal logical reasons. The logical structure of your question is the following implication:

If $f, g :[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ are functions satisfying suitable properties, we have $f = g$.

In other words

For all functions $f, g :[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$, if $f, g$ satisfy suitable properties, then $f = g$.

There does not exist a function $g$ as required, thus this statement is true.